# HTTPS request implicates a HTTP responseheader and a Mixed Content warning - how to avoid

Tags: php, hsts

In a PHP site I request images (user profile photos) from a PHP file, the image are loaded explicit using HTTPS as the entire site where HSTS are enabled.

The problem is that the site gives a "Mixed content" warning in Chrome and Firefox even though not a single asset are loaded using HTTP - all are either relative or explicit HTTPS in the sourcecode.

When I look at the network tab in Chrome developer tools, I can see that the image are initially requested using HTTPS but then a internal redirect 307 using HTTP are made, and finally the image are retrieved using HTTPS.
[HTTP request in Chrome network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRfrh.png)

The PHP file that returns the image has the request routed by index.php and .htaccess using a simple rewriterule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$     index.php?action=$1&data1=$2  [L,QSA]
```

And the PHP file are very simple as well

```
if(!isset($_GET["f"]))die("filepath missing");
$file = APP."/filecache/".$_GET["f"];
if(file_exists($file)){
  if(substr($_GET["f"],-3)=="jpg") Header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
  if(substr($_GET["f"],-3)=="png") header("Content-Type: image/png");
  header('Cache-control: max-age='.(60*60*24*365));
  header('Expires: '.date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+365 days")));
  header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate(DATE_RFC1123,filemtime($file)));
  readfile($file);
}else{
  die("no such file");
}
```

The webapp works "fine" but the mixed content warning really frustrates me, so I would really appreciate any pointers or ideas that might work.

The site is running on a DO VPS, Apache/Nginx with PHP-FPM 7.1.

Kind regards and happy holidays,
Mark

Comment: What happens when you visit the redirecting URL directly? You might want to enable log preservation in the Chrome developer tab to see what happens.

Comment: When I access the image directly I don't see the 307 redirect and only 1 request for the image, compared to 3 for each in the above question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why the redirect from https falls back to http.
I would work around using a RewriteRule with absolute URI including the scheme, e.g.:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?action=$1&data1=$2  [L,QSA]
```

I did not try that line in my .htaccess as I do not have such a use case, so please try yourself if this fits.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, doing that breaks the "nice urls".